# Extract a ZipFile

Tags: c#, compression, zip

How can Extract a ZipFile in C#?
(ZipFile is include file and Directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

As [**@Arnis L**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82062/arnis-l) mentioned, will have problem unZipping .Zip files. Cannot use GZipStream to open a zip file, try

[**DotNetZip**](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) or [**CGZipLibrary.dll**](http://www.dlldump.com/download-dll-files_new.php/dllfiles/C/CGZipLibrary.dll/1.00/download.html)

Comment: Can you remove the bulk of your answer that does not apply to the question please?

Answer (score 8):

Use a tool for that. Something like [SharpZip](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/johnreilly/default.aspx). As far as I know - .NET does not support ZIP files out of the box.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) =>

> There are 2 problems with this class.
>   - It does not handle ZIP files.
>   - It is dysfunctional, can actually inflate data in "compression".
>     There's something wrong with the logic. It's a known problem but as yet unfixed.

So - if you need to work with ZIP files, gzipstream won't help. Otherwise - it should work fine.

Comment: Does any library support RAR files?

Comment: @Tuoski http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737/net-library-to-unzip-zip-and-rar-files